# Oracle Express Edition 21c la carpeta de destino tiene caracteres no válidos

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, express, oracle-21c

he estado teniendo problemas para poder instalar ORACLE Express. He intentado solucionarlo de varias maneras pero no lo he logrado, y quisiera saber si usted me podría ayudar.

Siguiendo los pasos, después de descargar ORACLE Express, hay que descomprimir la carpeta y luego ejecutar como administrador. Luego de eso, aparece una ruta para poder instalar el programa. Es ahí en donde tengo el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

carpeta: \Lenovo IdeaPad\ tiene caracteres no válidos, sin embargo no he modificado nada en el nombre de esa ruta.

Habrá algún conflicto con el nombre del usuario o el del equipo? ya que antes el equipo se llamaba: "Lenovo IdeaPad" y ahora se llama "Abigail".

O bien se podrá cambiar carpeta destino o el nombre de la carpeta no válida?

Quisiera saber que me recomienda que haga en este caso.

Comment: Hola Abigail, porque no tratas de cambar el nombre de la carpeta de destino?  El problema podria ser el espacio en blanco

Comment: Ok! Voy a intentar buscar esa carpeta ya que todavía no logro encontrarla porque me parece que está oculta